# sql query which counts the top search terms and orders by that

Tags: sql

```
SELECT SearchTerm, CustomerID, CreatedOn
FROM         SearchLog 
WHERE     CreatedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
GROUP BY SearchTerm, CustomerID, CreatedOn
```

I want to add one more column, which will be COUNT(SearchTerm) and I want to order the query by the searchterm which is mostly searched for. and the column should say how many times the searchterm is searched.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this your group by is wrong if I understand correctly-

```
SELECT d1.CustomerId,SearchTerm,CreatedOn,d1.TimesSearched
FROM
 (
    SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(SearchTerm) as TimesSearched
        FROM SearchLog 
        WHERE CreatedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
        GROUP BY CustomerID
        ORDER BY COUNT(SearchTerm) desc
) as d1 inner join SearchLog on
   d1.CustomerID=SearchLog .CustomerId
```

Comment: I am getting 1 for each column, although the one below have the same searchterm

Comment: still same, just the search term is ordered DESC, the count is still by 1 in each column

Answer (score 0):

Is `CreatedOn` with or without timestamp?
If it's only the date part you could do:

```
SELECT   s.SearchTerm, s.CustomerID, s.CreatedOn, COUNT(1) AS search_count
FROM     SearchLog s
WHERE    CreatedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
GROUP BY  s.SearchTerm, s.CustomerID, s.CreatedOn
ORDER BY COUNT(1)
```

otherwise you need to strip the timestamp somehow (I don't know your SQL dialect)